# Matching sub string in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

First I apologize for the poor formatting here.

Second I should say up front that changing the table schema is not an option.

So I have a table defined as follows:

**Pin** varchar
**OfferCode** varchar

Pin will contain data such as:
abc,
abc123

OfferCode will contain data such as:
123
123~124~125

I need a query to check for a count of a Pin/OfferCode combination and when I say OfferCode, I mean an individual item delimited by the tilde.

For example if there is one row that looks like `abc, 123` and another that looks like `abc,123~124`, and I search for a count of `Pin=abc,OfferCode=123` I wand to get a count = 2.

Obviously I can do a similar query to this:
`SELECT count(1) from MyTable (nolock) where OfferCode like '%' + @OfferCode + '%' and Pin = @Pin`

using `like` here is very expensive and I'm hoping there may be a more efficient way.

I'm also looking into using a split string solution. I have a Table-valued function `SplitString(string,delim)` that will return table `OutParam`, but I'm not quite sure how to apply this to a table column vs a string. *Would this even be worth wile pursuing?* It seems like it would be much more expensive, but I'm unable to get a working solution to compare to the `like` solution.

Comment: If you have a column containing multiple kinds or quantities of data embedded within the value, and you want to query based on the component parts, wouldn't it be better to store the data in it's component parts rather than combined?

Comment: *"using `like` here is very expensive ... "* This seems like premature optimization. Are you actually encountering issues with speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your like/% solution is open to a bug if you had offer codes other than 3 digits (if there was offer code 123 and 1234, searching for like '%123%' would return both, which is wrong). You can use your string function this way:

```
SELECT Pin, count(1) 
FROM MyTable (nolock) 
CROSS APPLY SplitString(OfferCode,'~') OutParam 
WHERE OutParam.Value = @OfferCode and Pin = @Pin
GROUP BY Pin
```

If you have a relatively small table you can probably get away with this. If you are working with a large number of rows or encountering performance problems, it would be more effective to normalize it as RedFilter suggested.

Comment: good point about the bug. I hand't looked at it that way. this table is quite large, but I am unable to change the schema.

Answer (score 1):

> using like here is very expensive and I'm hoping there may be a more efficient way

The efficient way is to normalize the schema and put each `OfferCode` in its own row.

Then your query is more like (although you may need to use an intersection table depending on your schema):

```
select count(*)
from MyTable 
where OfferCode = @OfferCode 
    and Pin = @Pin
```

Comment: My apologies, I should have mentioned that altering the schema isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to use `like` for this problem, which is standard for getting exact matches when searching delimited strings while avoiding the `'%123%' matches '123' and '1234'` problem:

```
-- Create some test data
declare @table table (
      Pin varchar(10) not null
    , OfferCode varchar(100) not null
)
insert into @table select 'abc', '123'
insert into @table select 'abc', '123~124'

-- Mock some proc params
declare @Pin varchar(10) = 'abc'
declare @OfferCode varchar(10) = '123'

-- Run the actual query
select count(*) as Matches
from @table
where Pin = @Pin
    -- Append delimiters to find exact matches
    and '~' + OfferCode + '~' like '%~' + @OfferCode + '~%'
```

As you can see, we're adding the delimiters to the searched string, and also the search string in order to find matches, thus avoiding the bugs mentioned by other answers.

I highly doubt that a string splitting function will yield better performance over `like`, but it may be worth a test or two using some of the [more recently suggested methods](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2010/01/delimited-string-tennis-again-final.html).  If you still have unacceptable performance, you have a few options:

**Updated:**

- Try an index on `OfferCode` (or on a [computed persisted column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx) of `'~' + OfferCode + '~'`). Contrary to the myth that SQL Server won't use an index with `like` and wildcards, this [*might actually help*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varund/archive/2009/11/30/index-usage-by-like-operator-query-tuning.aspx).
- Check out [full text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).
- Create a normalized version of this table using a string splitter.  Use this table to run your counts.  Update this table according to some schedule or event (trigger, etc.).
- If you have some standard search terms, pre-calculate the counts for these and store them on some regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the LIKE condition is going to have much less cost than doing any sort of string manipulation and comparison.

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/